# JavaEE - RMI code injection

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, ejb, rmi

I am developing a JavaEE application using EJB container and EJB.

Suppose I have class Student:

```
class Student{
 private int id;

 private String resume;

 public void clearXss(){
  ///some logic to clear resume from js scripts
 }
}
```

I have a standalone client and JavaEE server. Client conntects via RMI to EJB container. Client passes objects of Student class.

My question: is it safe to call `clearXss` on the object method, or it's necessary do an external method? I mean:

```
class MyBean{
 private void save(Student student){...}

 public void saveStudent(Student student){
  sudent.clearXss();
  save(student);
 }
}
```

vs

```
class MyBean{
 private void save(Student student){...}

 private String purifyXss(String string){...}

 public void saveStudent(Student student){
  student.setResume(purifyXss(student.getResume()))
  save(student);
 }
}
```

What I am afraid of is to call security methods of objects we get from untrusted client. That's why this is primary security question.

Comment: I dont have a good answer on this one, but I suspect it is unsafe in all cases to have a untrusted RMI client - especially if you enable remote class loading from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not simple question. On one hand you are fair enough worried about code injection at server side. On other hand as far as I know in RMI technology client object will be serialized only class data without methods on client side and restored (deserialized) on server side with server version of the class, and then both variants are safe against method injection on server side.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand two parts of the questions.

1. The question about security methods within objects. Usually everything having to do with security should not be of concern of an object not dealing with the security domain. Since when does a student object should deal with the way its resume is secure or insecure in certain circumstances.
2. RMI serializes and deserializes an object. Usually this means not transfering any kind of bytecode nor loading any class at all. What you are referring to is the download class files on demand from a class (file) server. As I am aware of you are in control of these servers. You can prevent clients form sending you unsigned classes. So this is of no concern.

As a conclusion I would say:

- First get every security aspect out of domain objects (unless they belong to that domain). Create yourself an utility class / API for that.
- Second check the class server controls and how they are implemented / configured within the RMI system (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html). They are under your control. It would be a huge problem if any client would be able to send your servers class files and your server would have to accept them. So there are easy solutions to that.